How do I fix the Access blocked: Authorization Error (Request details: redirect_uri=http://web/market/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/)?
ERROR MESSAGE: "You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of myapp.com, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request"
I am developing a web app (I am a beginner) and when I run it outside of docker, there are no authorization issues since I have added the redirect to the redirect_uri under Credentials in my Google Cloud Console (GCC).
However, when I run it in docker, I get the "Access blocked: Authorization Error" above.
I normally resolve this (when running outside of docker) by adding the specified address (in this case: "http://web/market/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/") to the redirect_uri under Credentials in my GCC. But when I try to register "http://web/market/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/" under the redirect_uri in my GCC, I am prevented from doing so and instead I get the message "Invalid Redirect: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).
Invalid Redirect: must use a domain that is a valid top private domain ."
What is going on here and how do I get around it? Thanks in advance.

Redirect uris must be HTTPS yours is running HTTP
http://web/market/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/

Also it needs to be the full domain not a path like that.
https://www.mysite.dk/complete/google-oauth2/


I not using a registered domain. The app is running on https://127.0.0.1:8000/. Following your suggestion, I tried https://127.0.0.1:8000/web/market/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/ and https://127.0.0.1:8000/market/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/ and neither worked
